# Can't run C file in Windows Terminal

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, executable

I installed MinGW recently and when I try to simply compile a c file it does that for me, but when I try to run the executable file hence generated, it says "Access is Denied". Is there something I can do about this?

The Console shows something like this:

[image]

Screen Dump of dir hello.exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjTDa.png)

Comment: Have you done `chmod +x` on the result?

Comment: Antivirus scanner?

Comment: try to change the permissions of the executable file

Comment: I'm on Windows so I can't use chmod.

Comment: I think you could use [this](https://windowsreport.com/access-is-denied-windows-10/#:~:text=To%20fix%20the%20issue%2C%20due,and%20then%20click%20on%20Permissions.)

Comment: On Windows, execute permission is by default in almost every directory. Is the message *Access is denied* you get produced by the command interpreter of by your own executable? Could you test with a simple "HelloWorld" program or show the source code of the program you use?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a simple hello-world program. Also, seems like everyone already has full control.

Comment: You only answered part of my requests...

Comment: I'm sorry.  I didn't understand the command interpreter thing. I am using the regular command prompt...

Comment: Please show the full console session - that is starting from the compile command ending with the "Access Denied" error

Comment: C:\Users\adrit\Desktop>gcc helloworld.c -o hello

C:\Users\adrit\Desktop>hello
Access is denied.

Comment: Are you running it in CMD or Msys console?

Comment: **command prompt** is actually an interactive program called **command interpreter** in the Windows world.

Comment: In the regular cmd

Comment: Change the command to `gcc helloworld.c -o hello.exe`

Comment: Please compile you program and then run it. When you have the error message, do a screen dump so that we see exactly what happens. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67823828/edit) your question and add the screen dump.

Comment: It still says 'Access is denied'

Comment: And with `.\hello.exe` ?

Comment: I did... There's not much to show... I put it in the question

Comment: The same thing...

Comment: You mean in the command to execute, right?

Comment: (I mean both). Maybe _Software Restriction Policies_ on the user desktop...

Comment: Please do the same in some other directory. Also make sure it is empty.

Comment: Do you see hello.exe? Try going out of the desktop, for examples in a subdirectory you'll create in "C:\Users\adrit\Documents".

Comment: 1) disable anti virus temporarily 2) compile and run 3) re-enable anti virus

Comment: Is your computer your own personal computer or is this a company computer connected to the company domain?

Comment: yeah I did that in mingw\bin... same result

Comment: It's my personal computer

Comment: Do you see hello.exe? (Use the "dir" command).

Comment: Yeah... I tried the anti-virus thing... didn't work

Comment: yeah... I see it

Comment: Can you add a screen dump with `dir hello.exe`?

Comment: Do the same in MSYS console. Also run the `file` command on the executable

Comment: Maybe you want to try another compiler? I suggest you use [Microsoft Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/vs/community/). It is free.

Comment: Are you using Windows native command interpreter? To be sure, type *cmd.exe* in Windows search box and hit return. Then change the directory to the one where *hello.exe* is and then type *hello* followed by *enter key*. Sorry, but I just want to close some doors.

Comment: As you probably have the dotnet SDK, a simple check to see if it's mingw or not: try `dotnet  new console -o myApp`, then `cd MyApp` then `dotnet run`. If you get a hello word, we have to check mingw...